# How to convert matlab image into 2d line graph

Tags: matlab

I currently have a set of grayscale images that i would like to represent as 2D graphs. Ideally each vertical column of pixels would have a mean colour based on how dark they are, and this would be represented by a point on the Y axis of a line graph. Any advice on how to achieve this would be massively helpful. Thanks!

Comment: `plot(mean(YourGrayScaleImage, 2))`

Comment: This gives the error - data may not have two or more dimensions

Comment: Sounds like your data is 1D. What is the format of your image? Can you display it with `image`?

Comment: Its a .bmp - but iam importing it from the array, so my image CH3.bmp is being imported as CH3

Comment: What is the output of `size(CH3)`?

Comment: The output is - ans =

     1     4

Comment: This is vector of 4 elements in a row, not an image. Did you try using `CH3=imread('CH3.bmp')` to load the image?

Comment: i have re loaded the image the imread you suggested and now have ans =

    60   130     3

Comment: So this is an RGB image, the third dimension is the color, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load and turn your RGB image into grayscale as follows:

```
CH3=rgb2gray(imread('CH3.bmp'));
```

You can then compute the mean of the columns of an array (images are 2D arrays of pixels) with the `mean` function:

```
AvgCh3=mean(CH3, 1);†
```

`AvgCh3` is now a 1D vector containing the averages over each corresponding column. Plot it with the `plot` function:

```
plot(AvgCh3)
```

Here is a graphical example:

[image: sine and its value]

*† MATLAB has a different convention for rows and columns of arrays and dimensions in an image, choosing the 1st dimension of the `mean` function on an image will compute the average along the height of the image.*

Comment: This works great! however, i have over 300 of these images, is there a way to allow me to open a folder and for all of this to occur automatically with each image? Also, is there a way i can smooth the graph, so its not so jagged

Comment: @user3500001 You're welcome. You can accept my answer if it solves the problem. Your other questions should be posted as other questions, once you spent a bit of time researching.

Comment: Great, will do! Is there a way to invert the intensity so the darkest column of pixels has the largest Y value and the lightest has the lowest?

Comment: @user3500001 Yes there is a way :-) try to figure it out, it's fun and more rewarding. Ask again if you are stuck showing your code.